# Android run Dalvik bytecode like inline assembly in C++

Tags: java, android, assembly, bytecode, inline-assembly

I'm curious if it's possible to run bytecode in Java for Android similar to how you can use inline-assembly in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).  In C++, I can run assembly and use its result in the program.

I don't want to inject bytecode during runtime but before actual compilation of apk.

```
// example of MSVC-syntax inline-asm syntax; not actually doing anything useful.
__asm { 
       mov bl, 2
       sub bl, 0
       div  bl 
       add   ax, 0
 }
```

Comment: [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/about.html).

Comment: @Elliot Jasmin is obsolete, and the question is asking about Android anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to embed inline assembly in Java. Java, the language is specified, and that specification does not include inline assembly. However, your Java code is ultimately compiled down to dex files.

The Android platform only sees dex files and doesn't care how they were generated. You can write dex bytecode by hand using tools such as smali. Further more, such custom classes can freely interact with classes compiled from Java or other languages. Note however that the Java language is stricter than the bytecode and non-Java bytecode is not guaranteed to uphold invariants guaranteed in the Java lanaguage.